# How to filter options for Laravel Nova select field

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a resource of type *Process_type*.

It has a BelongsToMany relationship with *Process_event*

It also stores a default *Process_event* as a BelongsTo relationship - I want the possible options for this to be limited to those in the BelongsToMany relationship, not the entire set of process events in the database.

I was expecting to be able to limit the options on a `BelongsTo::make()` field, but can't find a way to do this. So I'm falling back to using a Select field, and passing in the options via the options() method.

This is how my fields method looks currently

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    $options = [];
    $options['process_events'] = \App\Process_event::all()->pluck('title','id');
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        Text::make('Title')->sortable(),
        Select::make('Process Event')->options($options['process_events']),
        BelongsToMany::make('Process Events', 'process_events', Process_event::class)
    ];
}
```

As it stands, I still have all process events as options. How can I access the current entity via the `$request` object passed in, so I can look up the `->process_events()` on the model. I can't find any documentation on this.

Is this possible? If not, what is a better way to do this?